# PyCharm 2019.1 CE: No option to create/edit Jupyter Notebook (*.ipynb) files?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I updated Pycharm CE from 2018.3 to 2019.1 and lost ability to create or open an existing jupyter notebook file. The existing .ipynb file opens as a text file rather than a jupyter notebook with cells. I could open and view it fine on 2018.3.

I am new to PyCharm and indeed also jupyter notebooks, please let me know if I need to include more information.

This is what I already tried on the 2019.1 version:

1. Created a new project and installed jupyter package for the interpreter.
2. Started jupyter notebook server with the command (jupyter notebook) in the PyCharm terminal, with the working directory set to cwd.
3. Un-installed and re-installed PyCharm 2019.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So as per the support staff from JetBrains:

Starting with 2019.1 the PyCharm Community Edition (CE) does not support Jupyter Notebook. This functionality has been moved to the professional version only.

Answer (score 6):

You can type in Terminal:

```py
pip install jupyterlab
pip install notebook
jupyter notebook
```

and Notebook will be opened in browser

Comment: Thanks, mate! You are a saviour. I was just gonna switch to VS Code, but then I gave a shot and checked stackoverflow for hacks and, Voila!

Answer (score 0):

The trick that worked for me:

1. Create a .ipynb file from Pycharm.
2. Open the file and try to run any cell. It will be stuck in loading but it's ok.
3. Close Pycharm, re-open the ipynb file and run the cell again.

Voila! It works.